# How do I call useEffect when the trigger is in another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch data in a functional React component using useEffect (since the function is asynchronous) and I compute and return the data in h2 tags that was fetched in this component. However, I want to fetch the data when in another component (App.js) I hit the enter key. I have an enter key handler which calls a useState which I believe should re-render the component but since the useEffect is in another component, I am not getting the calling of the useEffect as I intend. What is the best method to press the Enter key and have useEffect in another component run?

```
function handleKeyDown(event){

if(event.key === 'Enter'){
  //this setHeadingText is a useState variable which should re-render in App.js
  setHeadingText(name);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Chris Abey, I would like to help you come up with a solution, but for that I need you to tell me about the structure. I am unable to visualize with the data provided, sorry. Let me help you rephrase it, I want to know if your `setHeadingText` hook is inside `App,jsx` and you wish to re-render your `Child` component with the `useEffect` hook when this value in the parent `App.jsx` changes?

Comment: Hi @HasanRiza, I apologize for not being descriptive enough, I'll try to work on that in the future. To answer your questions, my `setHeadingText` hook is inside the `App.jsx` and yes, I do want to re-render my 'Child' component with the 'useEffect' hook when the value in the parent (`App.jsx`) changes. If you would like to see more code, please let me know or if this is enough to help you visualize the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `useEffect` is specifying an empty dependency array (instructing to run only once):

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //fetch some data
}, []); // This empty array ensures it only runs 1 time
```

Have a look at this section in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

If your second component has access to your `headingText` state, try specifying your `headingText` as a dependency to the `useEffect`, and any changes to it should trigger your `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //fetch some data
}, [headingText]); // Only re-run the effect if headingText changes
```

Alternatively, remove the dependency array from your `useEffect`.

**Note**: this will cause the `useEffect` to run on every re-render

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //fetch some data
}); // run every time the component re-renders
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have understood properly, I think this is the solution you wished for:

1. The `headingText` value that is being updated in your `App.jsx` component should be passed down to your `Child` component with the help of `props`. So use `<Child headingText={headingText} />` while loading the Child component in your `App.jsx`.
2. Inside your `Child` component, receive the value like this `function Child(props)` or `function Child({ headingText })` if you have more values to pass, prefer props.
3. Now you can easily access the changes in value made in your `App` component inside your `Child` component with the help of `props.headingText` or `headingText` respective to the way you defined your `Child` in point 2.
4. To re-render your `Child` component, you will now use the `useEffect` hook with its dependency set to `headingText`, like:

```
React.useEffect(() => 
    {
    // Code for refetching
    }
, [headingText]); // or props.headingText if your Child component uses (props)
```

For example: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-waterfall-8gys7h?file=/src/App.js)
Hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

you can make a conditional rendering with the other component, so it get rendered only if you press `Enter` which would invoke an event:

```
//App.js
import {AnotherComponent} from './anothercomponent.js' //assuming the file is in src folder


function RenderOnEnter({pressed}){
   if(pressed){
       return (
            <AnotherComponent/>
)
}
       return null
}

function App(){
   const [pressed,setPressed] = useState(false)
    function handlePressed(e){
               if(e.target.key === 'Enter'){
                  setPressed(True)
}
               else{
                   setPressed(False)
}
                  
}
   
   return(
       <div>
       <button onClick={(e)=>handlePressed(e)}>Click me to obtain data!</button>
<RenderOnPress pressed={pressed}/>
  </div>

)

     
}
```